# Globally styling vertical and horizontal rules in both tabular and longtable

Tags: tables, longtable, colortbl

I would like to change all the horizontal rules in all tables to be blue and all the vertical ones to be red by applying a `.sty` file. I cannot change the actual LaTeX markup of the tables themselves as they are automatically generated by Sphinx.

Currently, I have this:

```
% my .sty file
% red vertical lines
\arrayrulecolor{red}
% table hline formatting
\let\myhline\hline
\renewcommand{\hline}{\arrayrulecolor{blue}\myhline}
```

However, this only works for `tabular` but not for `longtable`.

Here is an example document that illustrates this problem:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{longtable}

% red vertical lines
\arrayrulecolor{red}
% table hline formatting
\let\myhline\hline
\renewcommand{\hline}{\arrayrulecolor{blue}\myhline}

% I cannot change anything after this line!!!
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|}
\hline
a & b \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
c & d \\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
e & f \\
\hline
g & h \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Below is the output:

[image: pic]

As you can see, the `tabular` table is styled correctly with blue horizontal rules and red vertical rules. However, the `longtable` one is not styled correctly.

How do I make the `longtable`'s `hline`s behave just like the `tabular` ones?

I am using `pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019)`.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured it out. After digging through `longtable.sty` I found out that it was using `\LT@hline` so I overwrite these as well.

In a `wtf.sty` file I now have these:

```latex
% red vertical lines
\arrayrulecolor{red}
% table hline formatting
\let\my@hline\hline
\renewcommand{\hline}{\arrayrulecolor{blue}\my@hline}
\let\myLT@hline\LT@hline
\renewcommand{\LT@hline}{\arrayrulecolor{blue}\myLT@hline\arrayrulecolor{red}}
```

(You can inline this in your `.tex` document with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`)

It is an ugly hack but seems to work.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wtf}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
e & f \\
\hline
g & h \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|}
\hline
a & b \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
c & d \\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
e & f \\
\hline
g & h \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: pic]

**NOTE**: in general, overwriting built-in macros like `\hline` is not recommended. However, I have no choice here since I am trying to change the behaviour of generated output from Sphinx.

Comment: Feel free to design your tables as you want, of course, but now that you've figured out how to do it, and without any idea of the  context, my suggestion is: do not do it! I have no idea if Sphink can use the package `booktabs`, but you should take a look to this package and think twice why it is so popular in thi site.

Comment: There is a PR to use `booktabs` in Sphinx: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/pull/6666 but unfortunately it hasn't been merged despite being open for over half a year.

Answer (score 1):

`hhline` is a way to do such thing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ehhline}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\def\hline@color{black}
\newcommand{\hlinecolor}[1]{\def\hline@color{#1}}
\newcommand{\hsl}{\leaders\hbox{\textcolor{\hline@color}{\rule{0.1pt}{0.4pt}}}\hfil}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\myhline}{\hhline{!{\hsl}!{\hsl}}}

% I cannot change anything after this line!!!
\begin{document}
\arrayrulecolor{blue}
\hlinecolor{red}
\centering
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|}
\myhline
a & b \\
\myhline
\endfirsthead
c & d \\
\myhline
\end{longtable}

\hlinecolor{teal}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\myhline
e & f \\
\myhline
g & h \\
\myhline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, hhline is very useful indeed! However this is not the answer I am looking for, since I cannot change anything underneath the line that says "I cannot change anything after this line!" but your solution has clearly changed some stuff there.